# What is the best solution to move complex queries from controller into repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

during creating my app I threw `Model layer` and `Repository layer` to separate projects. Each form in my app is represented by its own `ViewModel class`. All `ViewModel classes` are stored in folder `ViewModels` in MyApplicationName.Web. During `GET request` for `MyDrafts form`, the following  function  is launched:

```
public ActionResult MyDrafts()
        {
            MyDraftsVM dataVM = GetDataMyDrafts();
            return View(dataVM);
        }


        private MyDraftsVM GetDataMyDrafts()
        {        
            MyDraftsVM dataVM = new MyDraftsVM();

            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                List<MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM> userInvoices = new List<MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM>();
                userInvoices = _repoExhibitor.Context.Exhibitors
                                                .Join(_repoExhibitor.Context.Invoices.Where(x => x.CreatedBy == User.Identity.Name && x.Status == (int)(ModelEnums.Invoice.Status.Przygotowanie)),
                                                e => e.Id,
                                                i => i.Id,
                                                (e, i) => new { e, i })
                                                .ToList()
                                                .Select(s => new MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM(s.e, s.i, UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, s.i.CreatedBy).DisplayName))
                                                .ToList();

                List<MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM> userCorrespondence = new List<MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM>();
                userCorrespondence = _repoExhibitor.Context.CorrespondenceSenders
                                                    .Join(_repoExhibitor.Context.Correspondences.Where(x => x.CreatedBy == User.Identity.Name && x.Status == (int)(ModelEnums.Invoice.Status.Przygotowanie)),
                                                    sen => sen.Id,
                                                    c => c.Id,
                                                    (sen, c) => new { sen, c })
                                                    .ToList()
                                                    .Select(s => new MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM(s.c, UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, s.c.CreatedBy).DisplayName))                                                 
                                                    .ToList();                                                    

                dataVM.Documents.AddRange(userInvoices);
                dataVM.Documents.AddRange(userCorrespondence);
            }
            return dataVM;
        }
```

MyDraftsVM class looks like this:

```
public class MyDraftsVM
    {
        public MyDraftsVM()
        {
            this.Documents = new List<MyDraftVM>();
            this.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBox.cshtml";
        }

        public List<MyDraftVM> Documents { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// layout path
        /// </summary>      
        public string Layout { get; set; }

        public class MyDraftVM
        {


            public MyDraftVM()
            {
                this.DocumentPartial = new DocumentMemebership();
                this.InvoicePartial = new InvoiceMembership();
                this.ExhibitorPartial = new ExhibitorMembership();
                this.CorrespondencePartial = new CorrespondenceMembership();
            }

            public MyDraftVM(Exhibitor e, Invoice i, string createdBy)
            {              
                InvoicePartial = Mapper.Map<MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM.InvoiceMembership>(i);
                ExhibitorPartial = Mapper.Map<MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM.ExhibitorMembership>(e);
                DocumentPartial = new MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM.DocumentMemebership()
                {
                    DocumentType = "Invoice",
                    Number = i.InvoiceNumber,
                    IssuingDate = i.IssuingDate,
                    CreatedBy = createdBy
                };
            }

            public MyDraftVM(Correspondence c, string createdBy)
            {
                CorrespondencePartial = Mapper.Map<MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM.CorrespondenceMembership>(c);
                DocumentPartial = new MyDraftsVM.MyDraftVM.DocumentMemebership()
                {
                    DocumentType = "Correspondence",
                    Number = c.Signature,
                    IssuingDate = c.IssuingDate,
                    CreatedBy = createdBy,
                };
            }

            public DocumentMemebership DocumentPartial { get; set; }
            public InvoiceMembership InvoicePartial { get; set; }
            public CorrespondenceMembership CorrespondencePartial { get; set; }
            public ExhibitorMembership ExhibitorPartial { get; set; }


            public class InvoiceMembership : InvoiceVM
            {
                public virtual int Id { get; set; }
            }


            public class CorrespondenceMembership : CorrespondenceVM
            {

            }


            public class ExhibitorMembership : ExhibitorVM
            {
            }


            public class DocumentMemebership : DocumentVM
            {
            }


        }

    }
```

I’d like to move complex queries with `joins` to `repository` and here appears the problem. I would call this problem “problem of the interaction projects” because project `MyApplicationName` .Web has reference `MyApplicationName.Repository`. If I would like to move queries to `MyApplicationName.Repository`, I have to move there also `MyDraftsVM object`, which belongs to `MyApplicationName.Web`. 
The only solution which I see now, is to separate `ViewModels` folder as a separate project and the give a reference `MyApplicationName.Web` and `MyApplicationName.Repository` to this project. I don’t know if this is a good idea so that’s why I’m asking you.
If it’s not a good idea, can you give me better solution to move those complex queries to `repository`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right way, moving the queries in separate repo project. But `MyApplicationName.Repository` should not know about your web project neither about your view models. It should work only with your domain models. So the option that I would suggest you is to use some mapping tool between your domain and view models like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).
This whould solve your architectural problems, I think.